# Joining specific columns from different tables, incorporating GROUP BY

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, join, group-by

I am trying to make a query that combines these two queries into one. I have tried various JOINS and haven't had any luck...

This is the two SELECTS...

```
SELECT     BlockSize, BootVolume, Compressed, SystemName , Label, Caption, PageFilePresent,
           [dbo].[CCS_DIGITAL_STORAGE_CONVERTER]('B', 'GB', Capacity) AS Capacity,
           [dbo].[CCS_DIGITAL_STORAGE_CONVERTER]('B', 'GB', FreeSpace) AS [Free Space], 
           [dbo].[CCS_DIGITAL_STORAGE_CONVERTER]('B', 'GB', Capacity - FreeSpace) AS [Used Space],
           100 * FreeSpace / Capacity AS [Free Space %]

FROM       CCS_Win32_Volume

WHERE      ((@p_ServerName = SystemName) OR (@p_ServerName = 'all'))

SELECT     [CLE_ENV_SHORT], [CLE_ENV_CAT_SHORT]

FROM       [dbo].[CCS_V_SERVER_INSTANCE_DETAILS]

WHERE      [CLE_ENV_SHORT] = @p_Env 
      AND  [CLE_ENV_CAT_SHORT] = @p_EnvCat
```

I would like all columns displayed in one table and GROUP BY [CLE_ENV_CAT_SHORT], [CLE_ENV_SHORT].

Is this possible? 
Thanks in advance!

Comment: See UNION... [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180026.aspx)

Comment: Do CCS_Win32_Volume and CCS_V_SERVER_INSTANCE_DETAILS have a column in common?  Do they both have a ServerName column?

Comment: @Jerrad yes, SystemName from CCS_Win32_Volume and [CSL_SERVER_NAME] from [CCS_V_SERVER_INSTANCE_DETAILS]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT     c1.BlockSize, c1.BootVolume, c1.Compressed, c1.SystemName, c1.Label, c1.Caption, c1.PageFilePresent,
           [dbo].[CCS_DIGITAL_STORAGE_CONVERTER]('B', 'GB', c1.Capacity) AS Capacity,
           [dbo].[CCS_DIGITAL_STORAGE_CONVERTER]('B', 'GB', c1.FreeSpace) AS [Free Space], 
           [dbo].[CCS_DIGITAL_STORAGE_CONVERTER]('B', 'GB', c1.Capacity - c1.FreeSpace) AS [Used Space],
           100 * c1.FreeSpace / c1.Capacity AS [Free Space %],
           [CLE_ENV_SHORT], [CLE_ENV_CAT_SHORT]
FROM       CCS_Win32_Volume c1
JOIN       [dbo].[CCS_V_SERVER_INSTANCE_DETAILS] c2 on c1.SystemName = c2.CSL_SERVER_NAME
WHERE      ((@p_ServerName = c1.SystemName) OR (@p_ServerName = 'all')) and
      c2.[CLE_ENV_SHORT] = @p_Env 
      c2.[CLE_ENV_CAT_SHORT] = @p_EnvCat
ORDER BY c2.[CLE_ENV_CAT_SHORT]
```

Comment: can you please explain what the c1. and c2. do? And I get a ton of errors. Thanks for the input though!

Comment: c1 and c2 are just aliases for the tables CCS_Win32_Volume and CCS_V_SERVER_INSTANCE_DETAILS.  It's shorter to type `c1.BlockSize` than to type `CCS_Win32_Volume.BlockSize`.  If two tables have the same column names, it's easier to prefix the column with an alias than the whole table name.  You probably don't NEED the aliases in this case (since it doesn't look like the tables have the same column names), but I think it's good practice to do so.

Comment: Your query worked just had to change c1.ServerName to c1.SystemName in the WHERE clause. Thank you for the help! @Jerrad

Comment: When I add a GROUP BY c2.[CLE_ENV_CAT_SHORT] I get the "Column 'CCS_Win32_Volume.BlockSize' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause." error. Do you know by any chance what can cause that? Is there any aggrgate function you can use that wont have an effect on the results (like just a way to rid of error)? @Jerrad

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish by grouping the results?  Can you post a sample of what your current results are, and what you want them to look like?  When you group by a column, it's because you are somehow summarizing the other columns (adding them up, averaging them, something like that).

Comment: I can explain what I want (theres thousands of results lol)... 

Categories (c2.[CLE_ENV_CAT_SHORT]),  I have PROD and NON PROD I would like so sort the list by this.

Comment: Just add `ORDER BY c2.[CLE_ENV_CAT_SHORT]` to the end of the query.  I've updated my answer.